Show that $X$ has $n(n+1)(g-1) + (n+1) d$ hyperosculation points.
The problem comes from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, Chapter IV, exercise 4.6. Let $X$ be a curve of genus $g$ embedded as a curve of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$, $n \geq 3$, not contained in any $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$. For each point $P \in X$, there is a hyperplane $H$ containing $P$, such that $P$ counts at least $n$ times in the intersection $H \cap X$ (proved here). If $P$ counts at least $n + 1$ times in $H \cap X$, we say $H$ is a hyperosculating hyperplane, and that $P$ is a hyperosculation point. Show that $X$ has $n(n+1)(g-1) + (n+1) d$ hyperosculation points.
An incomplete solution: Let $n =3 $, take $O \in \mathbb{P}^3$ not in any hyperosculating hyperplane, and $\psi: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$ is the projection from $O$. Denote the image plane curve as $\overline{X}$. In $\mathbb{P}^{3*}$, every point of $X^*$
corresponding to a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ which is an osculating hyperplane for some point on X. The hyperplane corresponding to $O$ intersects $X^*$ at $\deg X^*$ points. So
$\deg X^* = $# hyperosculating points of $\overline{X}$ = #inflection= $6(g − 1) + 3d$.
(The last equality comes from (a)). I do not know what to do next.
How to show $X$ has $n(n+1)(g-1) + (n+1) d$ hyperosculation points?

Hint: one way to do this is to convert the existence of a hyperosculating hyperplane in to the vanishing of a global section of a line bundle, then count the degree of that line bundle to determine how many points a global section must vanish at. (This may take some relatively involved work.)
